# Как исправить ошибку

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

помогите исправить ошибку
**Сама ошибка**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary, PID: 12989
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Words");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_words);

        RecyclerView_config.WordAdapter mWordAdapter = new RecyclerView_config.WordAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWordAdapter);
        Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new FirebaseHelper().readWords(new FirebaseHelper.DataStatus() {
            @Override
            public void DataIsLoaded(List<Word> words, List<String> keys) {
                new RecyclerView_config().setConfig(mRecyclerView, MainActivity.this, words, keys);
            }

            @Override
            public void DataIsInserted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void DataIsUpdated() {

            }

            @Override
            public void DataIsDeleted() {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FirebaseHelper.java**

```
package com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FirebaseHelper {

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mRefenceWords;
    private List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public interface DataStatus{
        void DataIsLoaded(List<Word> words, List<String> keys);
        void DataIsInserted();
        void DataIsUpdated();
        void DataIsDeleted();
    }

    public FirebaseHelper(){
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRefenceWords = mDatabase.getReference("Words");

    }

    public void readWords(final DataStatus dataStatus){
        mRefenceWords.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                words.clear();
                List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot keyNode : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                    Word word = keyNode.getValue(Word.class);
                    words.add(word);
                }

                dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(words, keys);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView_config.java**

```
package com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerView_config {

    private static Context mContext;
    private WordAdapter mWordAdapter;


    public void setConfig(RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context, List<Word> words, List<String> keys){
        mContext = context;
        mWordAdapter = new WordAdapter();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mWordAdapter);
    }

    static class WordItemView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView mWord;
        private TextView mTranslate;


        private String key;

        public WordItemView(ViewGroup parent){
            super(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.word_item, parent, false));
        }
        public void bind(Word word, String key){
            mWord.setText(word.getWord());
            mTranslate.setText(word.getTranslation());
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    static class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordItemView>{
        private List<String> mKeys;
        private List<Word> mWordList;


        public WordAdapter(){
            this.mWordList = mWordList;
            this.mKeys = mKeys;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WordItemView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new WordItemView(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordItemView holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(mWordList.get(position), mKeys.get(position));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mWordList.size();
        }
    }

}
```

**word_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_trans"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="184dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="184dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="77dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="684dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/main_word"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_word"
        android:text="Translate"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Word"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Word.java**

```
package com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary;

import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;

public class Word {

    private String word;
    private String translation;

    public Word() {
    }

    public void setWord(String name) {
        this.word = name;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    @PropertyName("translation")
    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    @PropertyName("translation")
    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_words"
            android:layout_width="411dp"
            android:layout_height="730dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `this.mWordList = mWordList;` Что Вы этим имели ввиду?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, я так пытался определить лист

Comment: @nikita_game а ты хоть джаву знаешь?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, я знаю. Я понимаю, что я жёстко затупил на этом моменте поскольку уже очень много строк написал и в этой проблеме столько нагородил всякой херни.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, за это извиняюсь. Надо успеть в дедлайн. Можете просто сказать в чём моя ошибка и, как мне всё исправить. Я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: если б я мог просто сказать в чем ошибка - уже сказал бы. Я не настолько злодей. Но я во-первых давно пишу на Kotlin и Java читаю уже не так свободно, а во-вторых у вас тут очень много кода и понять, в чем именно проблема - та еще задачка

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, хорошо спасибо, за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание, какие значения вы присваиваете

```
private List<String> mKeys;
private List<Word> mWordList;

public WordAdapter(){
   this.mWordList = mWordList; // null = null
   this.mKeys = mKeys; // null = null
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return mWordList.size(); // Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
}
```

Comment: а, что нужно, чтобы это исправить?

Comment: смотря что вы хотите. можно передавать значения  в параметрах конструктора, а можно  просто инициализировать пустым листом `this.mWordList = new ArrayList<>(); this.mKeys = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Ошибка пропала, спасибо.

Comment: Обычно так и делают - инициализируют списки пустыми, потом, когда данные получены, их передают в адаптер - для этого в нём делают метод (ака `update(List)`, в методе  добавляют полученные данные в список и просят адаптер обновиться одним из методов `notify...`